# Differentiate function name and function arguments in sql grammar

Tags: sql, antlr, antlr4

With this [grammar](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/tree/master/ksqldb-parser/src/main/antlr4/io/confluent/ksql/parser) , I am trying to extract user written expressions from sql queries.

For example,from this query i'd like to extract FNAME,LName and name.

```
SELECT TRIM(CONCAT(FNAME , LNAME)) AS `name`FROM  CLIENTS;
```

[Parse Tree]

[image: 2]

I am able to extract 'name' with my listenor :

```
public void enterSelectSingle(ksqlParser.SelectSingleContext ctx) {
    super.enterSelectSingle(ctx);
    System.out.println(ctx.identifier().getText());
}
```

But when i try to extract "FNAME,LNAME" with `ctx.expression().getText().` i get `TRIM(CONCAT(FNAME,LNAME))`.

How can i differentiate, CONCAT,TRIM,(,) and , from FNAME and LNAME since they are all recognized as  identifiers and hidden behind expression in the grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the grammar, you can see the following parser rule for ``primaryExpression```

(It's referenced in the tree graph in your question):

```
primaryExpression
    : literal                                                                             #literalExpression
    | identifier STRING                                                                   #typeConstructor
    | CASE valueExpression whenClause+ (ELSE elseExpression=expression)? END              #simpleCase
    | CASE whenClause+ (ELSE elseExpression=expression)? END                              #searchedCase
    | CAST '(' expression AS type ')'                                                     #cast
    | ARRAY '[' (expression (',' expression)*)? ']'                                       #arrayConstructor
    | MAP '(' (expression ASSIGN expression (',' expression ASSIGN expression)*)? ')'     #mapConstructor
    | STRUCT '(' (identifier ASSIGN expression (',' identifier ASSIGN expression)*)? ')'  #structConstructor
    | identifier '(' ASTERISK ')'                                                           #functionCall
    | identifier '(' (functionArgument (',' functionArgument)* (',' lambdaFunction)*)? ')' #functionCall
    | value=primaryExpression '[' index=valueExpression ']'                               #subscript
    | identifier                                                                          #columnReference
    | identifier '.' identifier                                                           #qualifiedColumnReference
    | base=primaryExpression STRUCT_FIELD_REF fieldName=identifier                        #dereference
    | '(' expression ')'                                                                  #parenthesizedExpression
    ;
```

The alternative that matches your column reference is the `#columnReference` alternative.

That means, in your listener, you can override the `enterColumnReference` method, like so (to match *ONLY* that alternative of the `parseExpression` rule). It has only a single `identifier` rule member, so you just reference it:

```java
    @Override
    public void enterColumnReference(SqlBaseParser.ColumnReferenceContext ctx) {
        System.out.println(ctx.identifier().getText());
    }
```

With that override (in addition to yours), I get the following output:

```
`name`
FNAME
LNAME
```

This grammar labels all of the alternatives on the parser rules (as least as far as I noticed).  This makes it relatively easy to intercept (or listen in) on very specific parser rule alternatives. Each labeled alternative gets it's own `enter*` and `exit*` method along with a specific `*Context` class to make access to the rule members pretty straightforward.

In your case, it appears that you may only be concerned with that alternative *IF* it's a `functionArgument`.  If that's the case, you can introduce a bit of state management in your listener to track that:

```
public class MyListener extends SqlBaseBaseListener {
    private boolean isFunctionArgument = false;

    @Override
    public void enterSelectSingle(SqlBaseParser.SelectSingleContext ctx) {
        System.out.println(ctx.identifier().getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void enterFunctionArgument(SqlBaseParser.FunctionArgumentContext ctx) {
        isFunctionArgument = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void exitListFunctions(SqlBaseParser.ListFunctionsContext ctx) {
        isFunctionArgument = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void enterColumnReference(SqlBaseParser.ColumnReferenceContext ctx) {
        if (isFunctionArgument) {
            System.out.println(ctx.identifier().getText());
        }
    }
}
```

In your example, this doesn't change the output, but should give you an idea of how to select more specific usage contexts.

In the sense of "you CAN get there from here", it is possible:

```java
    @Override
    public void enterSelectSingle(SqlBaseParser.SelectSingleContext ctx) {
        System.out.println(ctx.identifier().getText());
        SqlBaseParser.BooleanDefaultContext bdc = (SqlBaseParser.BooleanDefaultContext) ctx.expression().booleanExpression();
        SqlBaseParser.ValueExpressionDefaultContext cev = (SqlBaseParser.ValueExpressionDefaultContext) bdc.predicated().valueExpression();
        SqlBaseParser.FunctionCallContext fc = (SqlBaseParser.FunctionCallContext) cev.primaryExpression();
        for (SqlBaseParser.FunctionArgumentContext fa : fc.functionArgument()) {
            SqlBaseParser.BooleanDefaultContext bdcfa = (SqlBaseParser.BooleanDefaultContext) fa.expression().booleanExpression();
            SqlBaseParser.ValueExpressionDefaultContext cevfa = (SqlBaseParser.ValueExpressionDefaultContext) bdcfa.predicated().valueExpression();
            SqlBaseParser.FunctionCallContext fc2 = (SqlBaseParser.FunctionCallContext) cevfa.primaryExpression();
            for (SqlBaseParser.FunctionArgumentContext fa2 : fc2.functionArgument()) {
                SqlBaseParser.BooleanDefaultContext bdcfa2 = (SqlBaseParser.BooleanDefaultContext) fa2.expression().booleanExpression();
                SqlBaseParser.ValueExpressionDefaultContext cevfa2 = (SqlBaseParser.ValueExpressionDefaultContext) bdcfa2.predicated().valueExpression();
                SqlBaseParser.ColumnReferenceContext cr = (SqlBaseParser.ColumnReferenceContext) cevfa2.primaryExpression();
                System.out.println(cr.identifier().getText());
            }
        }
    }
```

It's a tough path (and I just directly cast types where you should definitely do an `instanceof` tests.)

It's also VERY brittle.  Any little structure change and this code breaks.  Consequently, you'd need a lot of logic to navigate all possible permutations of the parseTree under your `singleSelect`

A better approach (leveraging what listeners do for you): Notice: I changed `enterSelectSingle` to `exitSelectSingle`.  You need to wait until you've listened to the child nodes to gather the parameters and print the on the way out.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyListener extends SqlBaseBaseListener {
    private boolean isFunctionArgument = false;
    private final ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void exitSelectSingle(SqlBaseParser.SelectSingleContext ctx) {
        System.out.println(ctx.identifier().getText());
        for (String arg : args) {
            System.out.println(arg);
        }
        args.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public void enterFunctionArgument(SqlBaseParser.FunctionArgumentContext ctx) {
        isFunctionArgument = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void exitListFunctions(SqlBaseParser.ListFunctionsContext ctx) {
        isFunctionArgument = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void enterColumnReference(SqlBaseParser.ColumnReferenceContext ctx) {
        if (isFunctionArgument) {
            args.add(ctx.identifier().getText());
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: even this code (for the sake of simplicity) does not handle nested function calls (for that you'd need to create a stack of ArrayLists, and then push/pop as you enter/exit functions.

I typically write code to visit my parseTree creating the simplified internal tree that I want to deal with in my program, but that's a MUCH longer answer than this, already lengthy, reply.

In short (too late), it can be complex, and you have to deal with that complexity unless you KNOW that you only need to deal with a simpler subset of cases.

Comment: Thank you! I now understand how the columnReference works. Is it possible to acces ColumnReferenceContext ctx since the enterSelectSingle function? I should have explain it in my post but my goal is to create an object that contains Sources[] array and Destination[] array of every select item. Example Sources =[FNAME,LNAME] and Destinations =[name]. Visitors seems as a solution but there is too many "middle rules"

Comment: I've amended my response to address your comment.  Many people find that ParseTrees are a bit overwhelming in detail, and deal with that complexity in different ways.  It depends a LOT of whether you can make simplifying assumptions.

Comment: Thank you for taking you time to answer! I would probably be dealing just with a small subset of classes. I was already trying out a slightly different version of your second approach and it seems to work with this query.